# Chef / kitchen - how to generate from a template locally (without creating the VM)

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, erb

I have a Chef cookbook. One of it's goals is to generate configuration file from a `.erb` template. That's done as one goal in a recipe, and the template input map is filled from the `node` tree.

```
template node['bbcpd-bpds-api']['api_config_path'] do
  source "opt/bpds-api/conf/api/bpds-api.yml.erb"
  mode 0644
  owner node['bbcpd-bpds-api']['user']
  group node['bbcpd-bpds-api']['group']
  variables(
      :application_protocol => node['bbcpd-bpds-api']['application_protocol'],
      :application_port => node['bbcpd-bpds-api']['application_port'],
  ...
```

I would like to generate this template **locally** (i.e. to the dir with the cookbook source) without all the other actions which prepare a virtual machine.

Basically, I would like to have something parse the files in `/attributes` and prepare the `node` tree and then only run the ERB templating engine, without invoking `kitchen converge`. Or ideally, `kitchen` altogether. The preferred target environment is Java / JRuby / Maven.

Is that possible? Or is my best shot to separate the recipe with the template  goal above and to call `kitchen converge` with only that recipe? How to do that?

See [Kitchen commands docs](https://docs.chef.io/ctl_kitchen.html#syntax).
I can only see `kitchen converge PLATFORM` as an option - I could add a suite. But I don't know what then.

There's also [`run_lists`](https://docs.chef.io/run_lists.html). But I don't see an explanation of what is run by what form of the runlist entry.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Chef only operates in the context of converging a node. You could write your own code generator of some kind, but it would be unrelated to Chef for the most part (though you might be able to jury rig `chef-apply` into being helpful, maybe?).